# psql ^C takes long time to cancel query

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using psql to query a large database. and (understandably) many queries that I type in take a long time.  I typically want to cancel these queries and so I enter `^C`, and psql responds with the message

```
Cancel request sent
```

This cancel request sometimes cancels queries quickly (milliseconds), but sometimes takes very long times (>10 minutes) to cancel the query and display a prompt where I can type in new commands.  These long cancel times even happen on queries that have only been running less than a second.

Why does psql take so long to cancel some queries?  And what can I do to make psql cancel the queries faster?

---

Version info:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

Comment: There's a lot of machinery between your keyboard and the database server (even if the server is local). An analogy would be launching a satellite: depending on its trajectory there will be only a few points at which you can command it to return to base if you change your mind. So, think twice before you run the query; you can't do anything to "cancel the queries faster", unless you're willing to restart Postgres (and even then it won't be as fast as you think).

Comment: @mustaccio People regularly ask about how to speed up queries, and cancelling queries should be no slower than successful queries, so I think this is still a reasonable question.  Also, I can easily start a new instance of psql, use `pg_terminate_backend` to cancel the previous query, and then reissue a new query in the same psql instance.  It would be nice to not have to resort to those measures though.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, however unsubstantiated it is.

Comment: @mustaccio If taking >10 minutes to cancel a query is expected behavior, then I would like to learn the details about why, as this is very counterintuitive to me.

Comment: Strongly suggest you ask the Postgres developers why this is. Not all questions are best asked here.
When you hear back from them, you can answer your own question with your findings.

Comment: Note that terminating a backend does a lot more than just cancel a query! It kills the entire session for that user.

Answer (score 1):

I usually see this when the resultset is large, and has already started to be sent to the client.  The client (apparently, I have not dug into the source code of this) still needs to read everything that was in the pipeline to be sent to it but not yet received, and this can take a long time, especially if the client is in the midst of a swap storm.

Are you using any third party or little-used extensions?

If these aren't the case for you, you will need to provide a reproducer or do some investigation of your own.  While you wait for the cancel to take effect, what is busy on your system?  Just the `psql` process itself, just the `postgres` backend it was connected to, or both?  Can you run `perf` on the busy process and see what it is doing?  Or attach `gdb` to it and get some backtraces at random times?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your query (which you didn't show) calls C code from third-party extensions that forgot to call `CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS` regularly, this is a PostgreSQL bug that you should report. Include the statement and its execution plan in the report.